# call-by-reference with an int array. 2 functions

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

hey i try a call by reference from an int array:

```
void function2(int stapel,int colour){
  stapel[1]=stapel[0]
  stapel[0]=colour;
}

void function1(int stapel){
  int colour=2;
  function2(stapel,colour);
}
int main(){
  int *stapel;
  stapel=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);

  function1(stapel);
}
```

whats wrong? :O i want to use stapel now in my main function.

Comment: What's wrong: your compiler is completely misconfigured or you are ignoring its warnings. Any half-decent compiler would give a warning for this code.

Comment: C doesn't call by reference, nor does it pass arguments by reference. C always passes by value. Pointers just happen to have a memory address as their value.

Answer (score 4):

You had wrong function declarations, your functions are receiving pointers.

You need to use

```
void function2(int *stapel,int colour){...
void function1(int *stapel){...
```

Instead of just `int stape`. This is the complete code:

```
void function2(int *stapel,int colour){
    stapel[1]=stapel[0]
    stapel[0]=colour;
}

void function1(int *stapel){
  int colour=2;
  function2(stapel, colour);
}

int main(){
    int *stapel;

    stapel=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    function1(stapel);

    free(stapel); // Also free the memory
}
```

As pointed out in the comment, also remember to free the memory at the end (here it makes no actual difference because the program will be terminated, but is always a good practice).

Comment: The *complete* code could perhaps call `free` just to be tidy

Answer (score 1):

In the `main` function you are passing a pointer to `int` as argument, but the functions does not take pointer to `int`. Change the functions to take pointers. The errors you get should be pretty obvious in this regard.

You also have a ordering-problem in our `function2` where you use uninitialized data to initialize `stapel[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

`stape1` is a pointer to `int` and you can not pass it as argument to a function that expects a integer value. However from the use in the function bodies it seems you should change the function declaration to expect `int*` instead of `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 Edit this

 function1(int *stapel)

 and

 function2(int *stapel,int colour)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not "calling-by-reference" you just say `int stape1` in the function signature, if you wish to use a reference (or an array) in C pass a pointer.

```
void function1(int * stapel){
//...
}
```

Then you can pass the pointer from main

```
function1(stapel);
```

Don't forget to `free` it afterwards

```
free(stape1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to use int *stapel in the function parameter list.  I think int stapel is a value of type int pushed on the stack of the function.  I think int *stapel is a pointer to an address pushed on the stack.  Finally, I seem to remember using &stapel to dereference the pointer.  It has been a long time for me.  I am sure one of the bright folks will give you a better answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void function2(int *stapel,int colour){
stapel[0]=colour;
stapel[1]=stapel[0];


}


void function1(int *stapel){
int colour=2;
function2(stapel,colour);

}
int main(){

int *stapel;
stapel=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);

function1(stapel);
printf("stapel[0]=%d    stapel[1]=%d",stapel[0],stapel[1]);
return 0;
}
```

try this code it works correct.......
in your program you are passing a pointer but defined it as integer

and there are other problem that i corrected ........

if you have any confusion you can ask............